# How to find the most frequent word of each file in a directory?

Tags: bash, text-processing, files

I need to find the most frequent word of each file in a directory and print it like this :

```
12 my /home/test/file1.txt
5 you /home/test/file3.txt
7 hello /home/test/file4.txt
```

I tried:

```
for tmp in <path> 
    do
   tr -c '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' < "$tmp" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head  -1 
   done
```

It doesn't work

Comment: Add the `-s` option to `tr` otherwise you'll count empty lines.

Comment: Tnx!! It works now!! but it doesnt print the path of the file near the words... you know why?

Comment: regarding the file path, you could add it several ways; one way: `echo $(tr -sc ... head -1) "$tmp"

Answer (score 4):

I would use `grep` with `-o` to print only the matched string top extract the words:

```
$ for file in *; do 
    printf '%s : %s\n' "$(grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]+' "$file" | sort | uniq -c | 
        sort -rn | head -n1)" "$file" 
done
      8 no : file1
     10 so : file2
     12 in : file3
```

Alternatively, if your `grep` doesn't support `-o`, you can use `tr` to replace all whitespace and punctuation characters with `\n`, filter through `grep .` to skip blank lines and then count:

```
$ for file in *; do 
    printf '%s : %s\n' "$(tr '[[:punct:]][[:space:]]' '\n' < "$file" | grep . | 
      sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n1)" "$file" 
done
  8 no : file1
 10 so : file2
 12 in : file3
```